# Nginx Passenger returning 500s for every request

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, mongodb

Up until this point I've been using the standalone passenger (nginx-based) for my application. Everything works fine.

I've decided to move to an nginx based solution since I need to be able to support multiple sites.

I've followed the usual guides, using the passenger nginx installation and everything works fine.

I've configured my nginx as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /www/myproject/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

The server starts up as expected but every time www.mydomain.com is accessed, the server returns a 500.

It seems like things are starting as expected because I had at one point forgotten to start the mongo daemon and got a passenger error showing that it couldn't connect to the mongo server. So at least it's running SOMETHING. Once I turned on the daemon, it went back to throwing 500s.

I've checked the logs, I get nothing in my `logs/production.log`. Nginx has nothing in the `error.log` and `access.log` has this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2012:11:14:51 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20110412 CentOS/3.6.9-2.el6.centos Firefox/3.6.9"
```

My mongo logs are spitting out the usual stuff:

```
Wed Feb 22 11:14:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47013 #1
Wed Feb 22 11:14:44 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:47013
Wed Feb 22 11:14:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47015 #2
Wed Feb 22 11:14:44 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:47015
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47017 #3
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47019 #4
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:47019
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47021 #5
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:47021
Wed Feb 22 11:14:51 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47023 #6
```

I'm really not much of a sysadmin (as you can probably tell) so any suggestions are welcome. If I left out any information, please tell me.

Thanks so much,

Ian

### EDIT

Issue has been fixed thanks to robotrobert's suggestion - I tried to rails server and found out that there was a bundler issue. Once fixing that, it still didn't work. However, setting the environment to production fixed that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems that rails doesn't do/render anything for the request.

For start try add the following to server scope:

> rails_env production;

If it's not working you could try running your app with default webrick server, and check what it is rendering on `<yourdomain>:3000`